# Is there any way to Update My Android app file without the User updating the App?

Tags: java, android, google-play, auto-update

I am making an Android App which needs it's Assets file to be updated every 2-3 days.

Is there any way through which I could update the files without having users to update the app twice a week?

Files sizes are very small not even an Mb

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should know that files in assets are read only. Hence they are not updatable. But of course there is a solution for your problem..

Comment: `Files sizes are very small not even an Mb` Nice that you consider 1MB small ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the updated files on a server on the internet.

At every startup your app checks if there are updated files.

If so, the updated files are downloaded

The rest i leave to you..